# Initializing an object with and without new operator

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

If I have a class `Rectangle`

```
class Rectangle{

private:
    double width;
    double height;


public:
void    Set(double w , double l){
    width   = w;
    height  = l;
}
};
```

and I decleare an object such:

```
Rectangle *Obj;
```

and then try to initialize its properties:

```
Obj->Set(3,5);
```

the compiler shows at run-time: `The variable 'Obj' is being used without being initialized.`

The problem can be solved by:

```
Rectangle *Obj=new Rectangle;
```

I would ask about the reason! And why the compiler doesn't show any error at compiling time?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
Rectangle *Obj;
```

just defines a **pointer** to an object of class `Rectangle`. Defining a pointer does not reserve any memory *for the object itself, just for the pointer*. Thus, if you access the pointer, you will likely end up at an address in memory that doesn't even belong to your process. However, the compiler cannot know that you haven't initialized the pointer (the keyword here is aliasing) and hence cannot output an error message.

The solution is either using `new` like you suggested, or declare an instance of `Rectangle` like so:

```
Rectangle Obj;
```

which will call a default constructor. You can then set your members using

```
Obj.Set(3, 5);
```

Comment: Just a nit, but `Rectangle* Obj;` doesn't just _declare_; it _defines_ as well.  And it does reserve memory; enough memory to store a pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze: You are of course right. I'll update my answer right away

Answer (score 8):

> and I decleare an object such:
>
> ```
> Rectangle *Obj;
> ```

Wrong, this declares a **pointer**, not an object. Pointers have to be initialized either using `new` or by assigning them the address of an existing object.

Comment: A pointer is an object, at least in C++.  This defines an object with type `Rectangle*`.  Uninitialized, of course.

Answer (score 5):

Mmm a bit of confusion there:

> the compiler shows at run-time: The variable 'Obj' is being used without being initialized

That is what you'd call **compile time**. Just straightening out the jargon.

Also, the simplest way would be to

```
Rectangle Obj;
Obj.Set(3,5);
```

which is sufficient for most scenarios, except dynamic allocations, or polymorphic containers:

```
std::vector<Shape*> v;
v.push_back(new Rectange());
v.back()->Set(3,5);

v.push_back(new Circle());
v.back()->Set(3,5);

//
```

Although **whenever using `new`** you should be remembering to `delete` as well. This can be quite a nightmare (in the light of exceptions, too). I suggest:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape*> > v;
v.push_back(std::make_shared<Rectange>());
v.back()->Set(3,5);

v.push_back(std::make_shared<Circle>());
v.back()->Set(3,5);
```

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest (and best) way be: `Rectangle Obj = { 3, 5 };`.  As a general rule, you shouldn't create uninitialized objects.  (About the only exception might be if you're reading into it, using `>>`, in the next statement.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: `Rectangle Obj` doesn't make an uninitialized object (at least I don't assume it is a struct with no default constructor AND no field initializers. Also, I tend not to throw C++11 specifics in beginner answers; shared_ptr can be used from boost, uniform initialization can not. (**PS** `width` and `height` are private anyway)

Comment: It does with his implementation of `Rectangle`.  And I'd missed the `private`; there's no way to create an initialized `Rectangle`.  He needs a constructor, not a `Set` function.

Comment: @JamesKanze: with **that** I heartily agree. It is also a bit off-topic for the question :)

Answer (score 4):

With `Rectangle *Obj;`, you are declaring a pointer to a Rectangle, but you haven't told `Obj` to which Rectangle it should point. You might set or instantiate `Obj` later on to an existing `Rectangle` or only if you require.

C++ is all about giving you precise control over your memory and performance. In fact, that's why it is used in some embedded environments! Automatically instantiating `Obj` poses several "issues"

- When do we free `Obj`?
- Who frees `Obj`?
- What about the performance implications of creating a `Rectangle` on the heap?
- Is this an environment in which we have enough resources (memory, CPU, etc) to even create the Rectangle, especially if it is large.
- Do you pass the address of `Obj` somewhere and then instantiate it at runtime through some complex method that we can't statically analyse?

What you do isn't a syntax error, which is what compilers throw errors on -- errors when compiling. An analyser (one is built into Visual Studio 2010 professional) might warn you that you're using an uninitialized variable, though that is optional and you may need to turn it on.

Answer (score 4):

pointer without new is declaring something without memory ..
SO u have to use new with pointer.
However 
Rectangle rect; 
will defaultly allocate the memory .

to check this,
make a constructor in Rectangle class like,

```
void Rectangle
{
  cout<<"Rectangle Constructor";
}
```

then,in main

```
Rectangle *rect; -->>O/P  -- "Nothing"
Rectangle rect2; -->>O/P  -- Rectangle Constructor
rect=new Rectangle; -->>O/P  -- Rectangle Constructor
```

Answer (score 2):

> why the compiler doesn't show any error at compiling time?

Because, it's **syntactically correct**. However, such statements will lead to **undefined behavior**, smart compilers will always issue warning.

In g++ you can turn such kind of compiler warning in errors.

Answer (score -1):

The statement rectangle `*obj` just means that there exist a pointer, that will point to the variable of type rectangle.

With this statement you are just creating a pointer 
not the instance of the object rectangle 
for the usage of this pointer you must store the rectangle type variable's address in the pointer

The two ways of doing it are by

```
obj=new rectangle;  //variable is created in the stack storage
```

or

```
rectangle r;
obj =&r;     //variable is created in the heap storage
```

Comment: I think it is reversed. the one with new is created on heap and the second is in stack.